# C# Dictionary - Access Value by Enum Key in Unity / Kinect Project

Tags: dictionary, unity-game-engine, enums, kinect, face

I'm trying to access a

```
RootSystem.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Microsoft.Kinect.Face.FaceProperty, Windows.Kinect.DetectionResult> FaceProperties
```

in Unity with the Kinect Plugin.

Thus, FaceProperty and DetectionResult are Enums:

```
public enum FaceProperty : int
{
    Happy                                    =0,
    Engaged                                  =1,
    WearingGlasses                           =2,
    LeftEyeClosed                            =3,
    RightEyeClosed                           =4,
    MouthOpen                                =5,
    MouthMoved                               =6,
    LookingAway                              =7,
}
```

and

```
public enum DetectionResult : int
{
    Unknown                                  =0,
    No                                       =1,
    Maybe                                    =2,
    Yes                                      =3,
}
```

Then in the debug mode, I was trying to access the FaceProperties:

```
FaceProperties                        // Count = 8
FaceProperties[0]                     // Incorrect types or number of arguments
FaceProperties[FaceProperty.Happy]    // The name 'FaceProperties[global::Microsoft.Kinect.Face.FaceProperty.Happy]' 
                                      // does not exist in the current context.
```

Do you have any ideas how could I possibly access the values of the dictionary FaceProperties?

Thanks in advance,
bertiooo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are missing the namespace:

```
using Microsoft.Kinect.Face;
```

Comment: Good Guess, but I already have this line in my script... But it pointed me towards another question: is the syntax of `dictionary[Enum.Key]` not correct in general or is it just a problem of my coding in unity? So to say, the problem lies anywhere else, according to a little coding test I wrote: [link](http://rextester.com/BNFCD7626). I will investigate in this direction further, so thank you very much.

Comment: I see your test fails on second attempt, Dictionary has no indexing. Simply because the items are not aligned in memory like a list or an array. The last version is the best one as it allows to check for the key to avoid exception. It is also faster than dict.ContainsKey

Comment: I tried to read the variable on runtime instead in the debugger watch panel and it works now.. seems to be a problem of monodevelop.. so thx again